# Button doesn’t work properly after subclassing view controller to base controller

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiviewcontroller, subclassing

I am making a simple app, which for now has 3 pages, and I wanted to have a base view controller to all my view controllers. But my button on the first page, which was working perfectly, that, when clicked, goes to the second page, doesn't work properly anymore, meaning, the button opens up a blank page and not the second page. But when I remove the subclass from the other view controllers, the button works perfectly. BTW I'm creating this app 100% programmatically. I know that I haven't provided the code or any screenshots of my code, but I hope you can help me out! Thanks! :)

```
// Setup the login button
func setupLoginButton() {

    loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    loginButton.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
    loginButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 25)
    loginButton.setTitleColor(baseColor, for: .normal)
    loginButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    loginButton.layer.borderColor = baseColor.cgColor
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25

    // Make it go to the main screen when pressed
    loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    addLoginButtonConstraints()

}

// Add the constraints to the login button
func addLoginButtonConstraints() {

    loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    loginButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    loginButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 335).isActive = true
    loginButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    loginButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true

}

// When login button is pressed
@objc func loginButtonPressed() {

    let mainPage = MainScreen()
    present(mainPage, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

So here, When I click on the login button, it should go to the mainPage, but it just opens up a blank page.

Here is the mainPage

```
import UIKit

class MainScreen: BaseAndExtensions {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

BaseAndExtensions is the base view controller.

Comment: Can you please provide code?

Comment: Do you change the pages with using GUI or programmatically?Its hard to say something with these informations.

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik yes, I am creating the app 100% programmatically

Comment: @Khushbu yes, do you want to code to the button or...?

Comment: so let us to see code @AbdullahAjmal

Comment: Okay, but how do I provide the code, it's super long, or do you just want the code of the button?

Comment: @AbdullahAjmal okay first provide button code

Comment: I have added the code @Khushbu

Comment: Why don't you just put a debug point inside `loginButtonPressed` and `MainScreen `'s `viewDidLoad` to see if that function is working or not?